# How could I go about plotting data in three different colors corresponding to some third/fourth/fifth dimension?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot

It's hard to write what I'm trying to do, so I'll go by example. Here is an example of the format of the data (values are made up):

```
Frame   Value (such as energy)   first_type     second_type      third_type
1               7.151                 0               1               0 
2               1.152                 0               0               1
3               2.253                 0               0               1
4               4.235                 1               0               0
5               3.252                 1               0               0
6               7.574                 0               1               0
7               4.768                 0               0               1
8               2.123                 1               0               0
9               14.24                 0               0               1
10              25.62                 0               1               0
```

I'm fairly certain there isn't any overlap where a 1 is for the `first_type`, `second_type`, and `third_type` columns. Also the header would be cut off, but that's easy to do.

What I want to do is make a scatterplot of frame versus the value, but in three colors corresponding to the rows that have 1 instead of 0. So if let's say `first_type` is blue, then frames 4, 5, and 8 are blue dots in the scatterplot. Some of the rows might have all zeroes, which could maybe be plotted in a fourth color.

Comment: Why not calculate `first_type + 2*second_type + 3*third_type`. That should leave each frame as a 0, 1, 2 or 3,  as long as no frame has two ones. Then use that to pick a color from a list or `cmap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to figure out which column the `1` is in, and with that you can use `np.choose` to grab a color from a list of colors:

```
which_col = np.where(data[:, -3:])[1]
colors = np.choose(which_col, ['b', 'r', 'g'])
plt.scatter(*data[:, :2].T, c=colors)
```

[image: colors]

Note: The above assumes that there is only one `1` per row. The length of the `which_col` output will be the number of `1`s found, and will only match up if there is only one per row.

I just noticed you said that some rows will have no `1`s. This will leave gaps in your `which_col` output. You could deal with that in this way. This also solves the problem of more than one `1` in a row: it'll color it (I believe) by the last value.

```
which_col = np.full(len(data), 3, int) # all of them are 3 for the imaginary "fourth column"
row, col = np.where(data[:, -3:])
which_col[row] = col   # in the rows with `1`s, record their `col`
colors = np.choose(which_col, ['b', 'r', 'g', 'k'])
plt.scatter(*data[:, :2].T, c=colors)
```

Comment: Hm, actually `colors = np.array(['b', 'r', 'g', 'k'])[which_col]` may be faster than using `choose`. `choose` is more useful for multi-dimensional indexing.

Comment: You can also do this with indexed color maps or boundary colormaps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all of your data in a series of numpy arrays (which are easy to convert standard lists to), you can use numpy masked arrays on the data, as shown in the code below.

Advantages of this approach would be the increased control over labeling and plot icons/colours, as well as the potential addition of a legend as shown. Hope this helps and is clear!

(See the figure at https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmUxt.png).

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x          = np.array([])
y          = np.array([])
first_type = np.array([])

for _ in range(0,10):
    x          = np.append(x,random.random()*10)
    y          = np.append(y,random.random()*10)
    first_type = np.append(first_type,random.choice([0,1]))

#Introduce second mask as opposite of first.
second_type = first_type!=1

plt.close('all')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (3.35,3.35))

ax.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x,mask = first_type),
        np.ma.masked_array(y,mask = first_type), 
        'ro',label='1st Type')

ax.plot(np.ma.masked_array(x,mask = second_type),
        np.ma.masked_array(y,mask = second_type), 
        'bs',label='2nd Type')     

ax.legend(prop={'size':8})
fig.show()
```